# CSS - which elements

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to change background color, etc. of a button (also making it centered on screen). I see this html code, and wasn't sure where I can make that change in CSS...

```
    <%= submit_tag("Submit", class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary") %>
    <% end %>
```

Also, I am trying to put a bit of space between the question (i.e. 
"Anything else you'd like to tell us?") and the entry form, and was wondering where I can make that change.

```
Anything else you'd like to tell us? <br>

<%= text_area_tag(:user_free_text,"", size:"60x6", class: "signup-entry")%>
    <%=hidden_field_tag "source", "lender interest page"%>
```

New to CSS/html, so really appreciate your help!

best

Comment: Please, add working code snippet on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You did not ask a clear question, but I am trying to answer it as much as I can.

CSS:

```
.btn{
    background-color: #ABABAB;
}
textarea{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thx. Tried changing background-color of ".btn" as you suggested but didn't work. also tried changing background-color of ".btn-sm", .btn-primary"   
".btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary" ".btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary" etc. but didn't work. what could be the problem...? thanks so much for your help!

Comment: please provide a link(url) to ur page if possible. maybe other style rules are overriding.